# huge memory used when load Multiple animations and textures with Cocos2d, how to solve it

Tags: memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a gameplay which needs load 27 texture altas (each one 1024 * 1024) before enter the game scene

but sometimes my game crash because receiving memory warning

I know 27 texture altas will use:
4 * 27 * 1024 * 1024 = 108mb memory
which is huge amount, but I really need to load them before entering game.

Is there anyway to solve my issue?
Any ideas will be very appreciated!

BTW:
I am using cocos2d 1.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Best suggestion is to review your design, and the 'need' for preloading all these textures. I tend to pre-load only the textures that are most frequently used (animations and static map objects).

For example, I have textures for animating walks on a map for 16 character classes. I regrouped the 'idle' animations in 4 textures, and preload these, because initially, when a soldier enters the scene, it idles. The moving animations are in separate textures that are loaded in real time, as a function of the direction of travel, for each character class in movement. When the characters stop walking (idle), i remove unused textures from the cache, as well as unused sprite frames.

Also: there are other avenues for memory management. You could use a 16 bit format for certain textures (RGB88888 is the default). You may gain by converting to compressed PVR format (once again this is lossy, but could be fine for some textures)

Look [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/61) and [there](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats) to learn more about picture formats in coco, and the relationship to memory consumption (as well as load, rendering speeds). But once again, before you start optimizing, make certain you have no alternative to the pre-load all approach.

Answer (score 0):

use jpg instead of png it will make that non transparent you can make that transparent by alpha image of that image it will help you reducing size almost half of you are using now.

Comment: even with jpg files, still with the same issue

Comment: @Haroon : cocos (CCTextureCache) will convert jpg to png whenever ios version > 4.0.

Comment: don't simply convert them reduce there size we can reduce the size of an jpg without losing the resolution.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg please explain more, what you are trying to say.

Comment: in One of my game i reduce the size 1/2 of the previous size.

Comment: @Haroon : look in the code for CCTextureCache around line 266 (in version 1.0.1)      // Issue #886: TEMPORARY FIX FOR TRANSPARENT JPEGS IN IOS4
  else if ( ( [[CCConfiguration sharedConfiguration] OSVersion] >= kCCiOSVersion_4_0) &&
      ( [lowerCase hasSuffix:@".jpg"] || [lowerCase hasSuffix:@".jpeg"] ) 
     ) {
   // convert jpg to png before loading the texture

Comment: Thanks for the information, I did't know that,i think making of the png at run time will effect the running memory usage. is That right ?

Comment: its a moot point anyways. JPG will reduce the physical size of the images in your bundle, but have the same number of pixels as the PNG version. For memory usage at runtime, the only things that matter are the number of pixels, and the size of each pixel (RGB4444 is 16 bits per pixel).

Comment: but greatly reduce the quality of the image